# is the pragmatic usage of 'jedoch' restricted to qualification?

Tags: usage

I read from Farrell's Dictionary of German Synonyms that **jedoch** is only used  to qualify a preceding absolute statement; however, this seems unsupported by the following example I read in Duden:

> Sie wollte anrufen, jedoch das Telefon war gestört; ( from Duden )

Could any native speakers of German give any tip on this question of pragmatic usage of 'jedoch'?

Comment: *Jedoch* is synonymous with *aber*, which is preferred most of the time. Your sentence is perfectly fine, It would be nice to know, what Farrell requires of an *absolute statement*.

Comment: The sentence is *not* perfectly fine. `jedoch` is subordinating in contrast to  `aber` and `doch`. The sentence should be: `Sie wollte anrufen, jedoch war das Telefon gestört.`

Answer (score 2):

> Sie wollte anrufen, jedoch das Telefon war gestört; ( from Duden )

Sie wollte anrufen, doch das Telefon war gestört.

Sie wollte anrufen, aber das Telefon war gestört.

They are all equivalent. I personally would use the last one. Since doch and jedoch are sounding old fashioned to me.

Comment: Ich würde auch das Lettztere sagen. Die Verwendung von jedoch in Kombination mit dem komischen Satzbau hebt meines Erachtens die Überraschung oder den Unglauben hervor. Vielleicht spielt es auch auf "... allein, mir fehlt der Glaube an".